# Does this raw SQL only do one trip to the database or many trips?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

I have this SQL:

```
string strTSQL = "Begin TRAN delete from MyTable where ID = 1";
string strTSQL = ";delete from MyTable where ID = 2";
string strTSQL = ";delete from MyTable where ID = 3 COMMIT";

using(Entities dbContext = new Entities())
{
    dbCntext.MyTable.SQLQuery(strTSQL);
}
```

This uses a transaction in the database, so all the commands are executed or none. But how can I execute this through EF, it does only one trip to the database or many?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string strTSQL = "Begin TRAN delete from MyTable where ID = 1";
strTSQL += ";delete from MyTable where ID = 2";
strTSQL += ";delete from MyTable where ID = 3 COMMIT";
```

Or, you can do

```
string strTSQL = "BEGIN TRAN delete from MyTable where ID IN (1, 2, 3) COMMIT";
```

Comment: Or since it's a single `DELETE` statement (in your second example), just don't even specify  `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMIT`, since it's being executed under an implicit transaction anyways...

Comment: @marc_s, of course you are right. It is just for case, when it can contains more statements but omitted in OP.

Comment: Yes, I know that I can use the where in, but I was talking in thoery, to know how EF works, because this is a simple example. Becaus If I want to delete records from two tables I need to use two T-SQL.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía, For your case you have first part of answer.